# Tokenize a mathematical infix notation string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string in [infix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) into a tokenized list, ideally with regex.

e.g. `((10 + 4) ^ 2) * 5` would return `['(', '(', '10', '+', '4', ')', '^', '2', ')', '*', '5']`

At the moment I'm just splitting it up by character, but this doesn't allow me to represent numbers with more than one digit.

I tried `tokens = infixString.split("(\d+|[^ 0-9])");` which I found online for this very same problem, but I think it was for Java and it simply gives a list with only one element, being the entire `infixString` itself.

I know next to nothing about regex, so any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `"((10 + 4) ^ 2) * 5".match(/(\d+|\S)/g)`

Comment: Will numbers always be natural? Because with `-1.5 + ((10 + 4) ^ 2) * 5` the solution would be another...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME I'd definitely like to account for non-integers. How can I include decimals in the tokenization?

Comment: w/ negative and decimal support: `"-1.5 + ((10 + -4.32) ^ 2) * 5".match(/(\-?[\d\.]+|\S)/g)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're passing a string to `split`. If you use a literal regex it will output something closer to what you'd expect

```js
infixString.split(/(\d+|[^ 0-9])/)
// Array(23) [ "", "(", "", "(", "", "10", " ", "+", " ", "4", … ]
```

However there's a bunch of empty elements and white space that you might want to filter out

```js
infixString.split(/(\d+|[^ 0-9])/).filter(e => e.trim().length > 0)
// Array(11) [ "(", "(", "10", "+", "4", ")", "^", "2", ")", "*", … ]
```

Depending on the version of JavaScript/ECMAScript you're targeting here, the syntax in the `filter` (or the `filter` function itself) might need to be adapted.

Comment: Or `.split(/.../).filter(...)` → `.match(/\d+|[^ 0-9]/g)`

Answer (score 2):

```js
let test = "((10 + 4) ^ 2) * 5 * -1.5";

let arr = test.replace(/\s+/g, "").match(/(?:(?<!\d)-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?|./g);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
code { white-space: nowrap !important }
```

`(?:(?<!\d)-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?`

`(?:(?<!\d)-)?` — Negative lookbehind. Catching minus sign, only if it is not a subtraction (has no `\d` digit behind)

`(?:\.\d+)?` — `?:` non capture group, `\.\d+` dot and one or more digits, `?` optional.